# Attempting to generate java class from uml in Acceleo

Tags: java, eclipse, uml, acceleo

I have been trying to get going with Acceleo. I use Enterprise Architect to design my classes, and have exported them as XMI.

In Eclipse, when I try to generate even a simple class using Acceleo, I get the following error.

Can anyone advise me as to what I am doing wrong?

Im using:

- Eclipse Kepler
- Acceleo Version: 3.2.2.v20120807-0831

  org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1' not found. (file:/C:/Users/Anton/git/magick/app.ui/app.ui.acceleo/Sample.xmi, 3, 76)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.common.utils.ModelUtils.load(ModelUtils.java:361)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.engine.service.AbstractAcceleoGenerator.initialize(AbstractAcceleoGenerator.java:457)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoLaunchOperation.run(AcceleoLaunchOperation.java:124)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2327)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.launch(AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.java:239)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.ide.ui.launching.strategy.AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.launch(AcceleoPluginLaunchingStrategy.java:141)
  at org.eclipse.acceleo.internal.ide.ui.launching.AcceleoLaunchDelegate.launch(AcceleoLaunchDelegate.java:51)
  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
  at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
      Caused by: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.PackageNotFoundException: Package with uri 'http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1' not found. (file:/C:/Users/Anton/git/magick/app.ui/app.ui.acceleo/Sample.xmi, 3, 76)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getPackageForURI(XMLHandler.java:2599)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.getFactoryForPrefix(XMLHandler.java:2429)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createObjectByType(XMLHandler.java:1306)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.createTopObject(XMLHandler.java:1475)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.processElement(XMLHandler.java:1026)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.processElement(XMIHandler.java:81)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:1008)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLHandler.startElement(XMLHandler.java:719)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMIHandler.startElement(XMIHandler.java:163)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:506)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1303)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:302)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLLoadImpl.load(XMLLoadImpl.java:175)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.impl.XMLResourceImpl.doLoad(XMLResourceImpl.java:253)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1518)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1297)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)
  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
  ... 14 more

Comment: Can you open the file C:/Users/Anton/git/magick/app.ui/app.ui.acceleo/Sample.xmi in your Eclipse?
Can you past the first node of the XMI file? The line starting with '<uml:Model ...'

Answer (score 0):

Acceleo doesn't find the URI package you declared. Indeed such a profile (http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1) doesn't appear to me to be an Acceleo registered package URIs, as I can't find it either. Did you edited it manually after creating your modules with any other available profile?
Maybe [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/440637/) might help you to shed some light over your question.